# Set store dynamic on a combobox

Tags: rest, extjs

Hi,
I have two combo boxes. The value of second combo box depends on first combo select. The user does select the first combo then the store of second will be set accordingly.

Here are my two Combos:

**Combo 1**

```
items:[
       {
          xtype : 'combo',
          name : 'cmbSATopFacility',
          labelStyle : 'color: black; font-weight: bold; width: 250px; padding: 10;',
          labelSeparator : "",
          id : 'cmbSATopFacility',
          width : 250,
          fieldLabel : 'Top MGMT Entity',
          triggerAction : 'all',
          store : Ext
            .create(
              'Ext.data.Store',
              {
                id : 'store',
                fields : [
                  {
                    name : 'id',
                    type : 'integer',
                  },
                  {
                    name : 'name'
             } ],
                 remoteGroup : true,
                 remoteSort : true,
                 proxy : {
                   type : 'rest',
                   url : 'pmsRest/facilities?sub_facility_id=-3',
                     reader : {
                       root : "facilityMaster",
                       idProperty : 'id'
             }
                 },
             autoLoad : true
        }),
        displayField : 'name',
        valueField : 'id',
        multiSelect : false,
        typeAhead : true,
          listeners : {
            change : function(combo) {
              /// code to convert GMT String to date object
              n();
              Ext.getCmp('cmbSAMedFacility').getStore().load();
            }
          },
          allowBlank : false,
          //enableKeyEvents : true,
    },
```

**Combo 2**

```
{
                                                            xtype : 'combo',
                                                            name : 'cmbSAMedFacility',
                                                            labelStyle : 'color:black;font-weight:bold;width:250px;padding:10;',
                                                            labelSeparator : "",

                                                            id : 'cmbSAMedFacility',
                                                            width : 250,
                                                            fieldLabel : 'Institution',
                                                            triggerAction : 'all',
                                                            store : medfacility,
                                                            displayField : 'name',
                                                            valueField : 'id',
                                                            multiSelect : false,
                                                            typeAhead : true,
                                                            //disabled: true,
                                                            listeners : {
                                                                    click : function(combo) {
                                                                    alert("hjdfhcsdj");
                                                                    n();
                                                                    Ext.getCmp(this).getStore().load();

                                                                    }

                                                                },
                                                            allowBlank : false,
                                                            //enableKeyEvents : true,

                                                        },
                                                    ]
```

Code to set store
    var medfacility = loadFacility();

```
function loadFacility(){
    topApp = Ext.getCmp('cmbSATopFacility').getValue( );
    alert(topApp);
    var urL = 'pmsRest/facilities?sub_facility_id='+topApp ;
    alert(urL);
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        id : 'store',

                            fields : [
                                    {
                                        name : 'id',
                                        type : 'integer',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name : 'name'
                                    } ],
                            remoteGroup : true,
                            remoteSort : true,
                            proxy : {
                                type : 'rest',
                                url : urL,


                                reader : {

                                    root : "facilityMaster",
                                    idProperty : 'id'
                                }

                            },
                            autoLoad : true
                        });
                        return store;
        }
```

I tried to `get` the `values in the second combo` but it didn´t work.

Comment: please suggest some solution

Comment: please clarify you question - and please indent your code. This will help other users to understand and help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WE CAN USE ONLY 
listeners : {                                           change : function(combo) { Ext.getCmp('cmbSAMedFacility').bindStore(n());}},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need describe a store for a second combobox, but without data (empty array).
And fill data for that store when you need by using [loadData method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData).

Hope this helps.